# Modifying const parameter temporarily

Tags: c++

I have a function which conceptually supposed to not modify the parameter. The parameter object is a big object (a vector with 10000 or more), so I don't want to create a copy. What is a moral way of doing this thing in c++.

```
double computeDelta(const vector< double > &grid, unsigned int index, double newvalue) {
     // compute something  on old grid
     double oldvalue = grid[index]
     // change grid temporarily
     grid[index] = newvalue; // this is illegal because of const (How to do this is question)
     // compute something on new grid
     // restore original grid
     grid[index] = oldvalue
     return // difference of old thing and new thing
}
```

Comment: passing reference is enough to not make a copy. Just remove the `const` keyword and everything will be alright. You can add a comment to explain why you const-qualification does not match the constant-concept of your algorithm.

Comment: I agre with @lip. Also, when you do stuff like this, make absolutely sure you're exception-safe. Best would be if you made restoring the old value part of some destructor.

Comment: How does the computation work? It may be possible to interpose a read-through wrapper. Also ... _why_ don't you want to create a working copy? Has profiling shown it to be a real problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. pass by value

This is guaranteed *perfectly* safe, and is easy. Only do something more complex if profiling demonstrates you really need it

```
double computeDelta(vector<double> grid, unsigned int index, double newvalue) {
    double before = compute(grid);
    grid[index] = newvalue;
    double after = compute(grid);
    return after-before;
}
```

### 2. pass by non-const reference

This requires the caller to trust you, and they may have to make a copy anyway if there are multiple threads

```
// I modify grid in-place, but promise to revert it before exiting
double computeDelta(vector<double> &grid, unsigned int index, double newvalue) {
    double before = compute(grid);
    // we can do something much more elegant if C++11 lambdas are allowed
    struct swapper {
        double &value;
        double oldvalue;
        swapper(double &v, double newvalue) : value(v), oldvalue(v) {
            value = newvalue;
        }
        ~swapper() { value = oldvalue; }
    } guard(grid[index], newvalue);
    double after = compute(grid);
    return after-before;
}
```

### 3. interpose a read-through wrapper

This is the only safe (const-correct) way to take a const ref without forcing a copy. It requires that the computation is templated on the container type (or alternatively on the iterator type, and you proxy the iterator instead). Despite avoiding a copy, it may be slower depending on the access pattern

```
double computeDelta(vector<double> const &grid, unsigned int index, double newvalue) {
    double before = compute(grid);
    // assuming only operator[] is used by compute
    struct overlay {
        vector<double> const &base;
        unsigned index;
        double value;
        overlay(vector<double> const &b, unsigned i, double v)
         : base(b), index(i), value(v) {}
        double operator[] (vector<double>::size_type i) const {
            return (i == index) ? value : base[i];
        }
        vector<double>::size_type size() const { return base.size(); }
    };
    double after = compute(overlay(grid, index, newvalue));
    return after-before;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `const` modifier from the function declaration.

Answer (score 2):

You can use const_cast:

```
double computeDelta(const vector< double > &grid, unsigned int index, double newvalue) {
     // compute something  on old grid
     double oldvalue = grid[index];
     // change grid temporarily
     const_cast<vector<double>&>(grid)[index] = newvalue;
     // restore original grid
     const_cast<vector<double>&>(grid)[index] = oldvalue;
     return // difference of old thing and new thing
}
```

Comment: Casting away the constness of a reference which binds to a `const` object yields undefined behavior.

Comment: @CassioNeri: It is hard to believe that the original `std::vector` to which the reference is bound would actually be `const`, if it was then you are right that would cause undefined behavior, but chances are that the real object is not constant.

Comment: @David Rodríguez: I completely agree with you but, strictly speaking, the author of `computeDelta` cannot make such assumption. I confess that I'm playing the devil's advocate here. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, don't modify the vector - in your simple example I don't see why you can't just work in a temporary variable.

*But* const_cast is arguably the right thing to do here, given that this is a situation in which you need to judiciously "cheat" on const-ness.  Note that this will break under multithreading, as your client code may assume you are not modifying the vector but you are. It will also break if you throw exceptions midway through, i.e., if you do not carefully guarantee atomicity.

Safest thing to do - just remove the `const` declaration and explain how it is modified in comments, i.e., modified intermediately.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `const` and be very careful to clean up after yourself.

If you're taking a `const` reference parameter, you are guaranteeing not to change it. If you start changing it, firstly this may well break horribly in a multi threaded program and secondly, ot is also possible that the vector is in some read only space [note: I'm aware this is quite tricky with C++ technology at the moment, but I could see a C++11 compiler working out it could create an initialised vector in read only space] - in which case calling your function will crash. Really, it would be better if it did not compile.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think casting away the constness is a good idea. You could get rid of it, or if you want to keep the constness, write some adapter code to handle it for you. There are many ways you could do this. e.g.

As you iterate over the vector, if you get to `index`, then you return your special value.

```
for (int i = 0; i < grid.size(); ++i) {
    if(i == index) { /* do something with newvalue */ }
    else { /* do something with grid[i] */ }
}
```

Or you could write a wrapper class to do the same thing

```
class GridWrapper {
public:
    GridWrapper(const std::vector<double>& grid, unsigned int idx, double val) 
    : m_grid(grid), m_idx(idx), m_val(val) {}

    double& operator[](unsigned int pos) {
        if (pos == m_idx) return val;
        else return m_grid[pos];
    }
};
```

Or you could use something like `boost::transform_iterator` to do the same thing.